# Flutter drag and drop coordinate system

Tags: javascript, flutter, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am looking to port a **Cordova-Vuejs-jqueryUI** mobile app to **Flutter**. The main functionality of the app is using drag and drop to **drag football players into a pitch**. Like so:
[view GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMLYf.gif)

The pitch has **position: relative** and the players have **position: absolute**. When a player is dropped, its offset is converted to a percent value based on its position on the pitch. This is basically: divide the size of the pitch by the offset position (element.offsetTop, element.offsetLeft) of the player element. The result of this is a relative value that I can store into a database for reloading later. This ensures player-position consistency across different screen sizes.

```js
function calculateRelativeUnits(droppableSelector, draggable) {
      const dropW = $(droppableSelector).outerWidth();
      const dropH = $(droppableSelector).outerHeight();

      const left = $(draggable).offset().left;
      const top = $(draggable).offset().top;

      const percentageW = parseFloat((left / dropW) * 100).toFixed(1);
      const percentageH = parseFloat((top / dropH) * 100).toFixed(1);

      return {
        left: percentageW,
        top: percentageH
      };
    }
```

But now, how can I port this functionality to Flutter? Is there something similar to pixel values based on position relative and absolute, that I can later convert to a percent value? I've been looking at the drag & drop widgets Flutter offers, but I haven't found a way to make this relative-positioning system work.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `InteractiveViewer`